# Having noneditable content in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an application where the user can some details from the textarea while some details are fixed. I want to add non-editable content in contenteditable. I have tried using a parent div that is contenteditable and any content that needs to be not editable goes inside a `contenteditable=false` div inside this container.

```
<div contenteditable=true>Editable Content Here
 <div contenteditable=false>Non-editable content goes here</div>Some editable text here
</div>
```

This approach works, but if the user presses backspace or the delete key right after the non-editable area, that div-contenteditable=false is deleted. I don't want that behavior. Is there a possible way to go around this behavior? I was thinking I would check the content before the backspace and if its a non-editable div just disable the default behavior for backspace, but how do I check what content is before the cursor? And is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: write script to keep them in content and add after remove .. or if removed ignore remove event

Comment: Why not keep the non editable content outside the editable div?

Comment: I donot want to separate out the content. I want the user to have the feeling to editing text freely in the text area, where non-editable text is just one big block that cannot be edited.

Comment: In that case just keep it outside and make it look like it's inside.